# Quel est le temps de la phrase « Le match sera diffusé à 17h00. » ?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical

Dans la phrase ci-dessous :

> Le match sera diffusé à 17h00.

quel est le temps de *sera diffusé* ?

Comment: I edited your question.

Comment: to the person downvoting, can you please set a comment why you downvoted?

Comment: @ON5MF I can't speak for the downvoter, but in general this question doesn't meet the standards for showing thought and effort. It's a very basic question that can be looked up pretty easily (e.g. "sera conjugaison"), and without any hint of what makes this a special case, this question is a model for an infinite number of "analyze this sentence so I don't have to" ones.

Comment: @LukeSawczak May be the downvoter saw this:-)! https://french.stackexchange.com/posts/31794/revisions (see original post)

Comment: @dimitris LOL, that would do it too!

Answer (score 6):

Tu te demandes quel est le temps de *sera diffusé* :

Premièrement, il faut que tu saches que c'est la voix passive du verbe *diffuser*.  Deuxièmement, le temps utilisé est le futur simple de l'indicatif (ce dernier étant le mode).

Donc

> **Être diffusé(e)** devient **il/ce sera diffusé / elle sera diffusée**.

À la voix active l'on dirait :

> Ils diffuseront le match à 17h00.

ou bien

> On diffusera le match à 17h00.

Voir ici

http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/diffuser

pour d'autres exemples d'emploi du verbe diffuser et ici

https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-9841.php

pour la grammaire.

Nota bene : on **ne** pourrait pas dire (forme pronominale) :

> Le match se diffusera à 17h00. (erroné)

C'est l'usage établi et la logique qui expliquent ça.